# Back button flutter

Tags: flutter

i would need to switch a color between one screen and another.
Through Navigato.pop (context, color) I can make everything work but when I press the back button of the smartphone the color is not passed
Come to solve?

Comment: What you're trying to say is not clear. Please explain in a clear way with an example, a picture possibly.

Comment: How can i pass some data with press of  physical back button in flutter?

Comment: I think you're looking for this: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data

Comment: You need to shows us the code you are attempting to use, so that we can try to help you. Follow the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass data via **BackButton**, then you can use **WillpopScope**. Wrap it in your top of widget's tree.

```
WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () async {
             Navigator.pop(context, color);
             return false;
          },);
```